# Return function does not seem to be working

Tags: python, return-value

I am trying to make a Blackjack game in Python and I made a separate function for each option to hit stay etc... When I call each function, I pass it the players hand total so far: ​​​

```
def hit(PlayerHand):
    PlayerCard3 = random.randint(2,10)
    print("You got %s" %PlayerCard3)
    PlayerHand = PlayerHand+PlayerCard3
    return(PlayerHand)
```

And then I print the players total hand outside of the function but it returns the previous value of PlayerHand and not the new value. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What does the code which calls this function look like?

Comment: your code works for me - I bet you're doing this: PH=5; hit(PH); print PH, instead of PH = hit(PH)

Comment: If `PlayerHand` refers to an `int` (sorry, but I don't know Blackjack) then you should remember that `int`s are immutable - you cannot alter them.  So when you do `PlayerHand = PlayerHand + PlayerCard3` you are creating a new `int` object, not altering an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are saving the new value:

```
print("New value is: {}".format(hit(PlayerHand)))
```

or

```
PlayerHand=hit(PlayerHand)
print(PlayerHand)
```